# Add-On Creation Difficulties

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, error

## Update After Comments

So, an original issue with my code was fixed: I wasn't registering the script to a menu. However, that has been addressed and the issue with the add-on not appearing has persisted.

Now, apparently the code I've put together works just fine for other users, and we have two instances of the code appearing in a menu and working as intended on devices not my own, so this indicates that there is something wrong on *my* installation of Blender.

Of course, I'd like to be able to use the add-ons I make, for the purposes of troubleshooting or even just making use of the functionality. However, I'm unsure how to fix this particular problem. What even do I try to change or adjust?

Below is the original text of the question.

---

So I'm trying to dip my toe into using scripts with blender, and made a script that automatically creates an object that I often find myself creating (a subdivided cube that has been cast to a sphere).

Now, I've tried turning the script into an add-on, since I thought it would be useful to have access to this script in general circumstances. So I've put it together into a python file and tried to install it as an add-on, however, every time I try to search for the command (by typing in "Add Block Sphere" in the search box), nothing comes up, and I am unclear what is happening.

At the same time, I'm now receiving an error from the ANT landscape add-on, so I'm bewildered. I don't know what is going wrong and could use some guidance on how to move forward.

---

The script is as follows.

```py
bl_info = {
    "name": "Block Sphere",
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "category": "Add Mesh",
}

import bpy
from bpy.props import *

class BlockSphere(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Creates a sphere with square topology"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.add_block_sphere"
    bl_label = "Add Block Sphere"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
    subsurf_levels : IntProperty(
        name = "Detail",
        description = "The general number of vertices involved. Uses a subdivision modifier.",
        default = 4,
        min = 1,
        soft_max = 6
    )
    
    sphere_scale : FloatProperty(
        name = "Scale",
        description = "The size of the object.",
        default = 1.0,
        min = 0.0
    )

    def execute(self, context):

        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        selected = bpy.context.active_object
        
        selected.scale = (self.sphere_scale, self.sphere_scale, self.sphere_scale)

        subsurf = selected.modifiers.new("Subsurface", 'SUBSURF')
        cast = selected.modifiers.new("Cast", 'CAST')

        subsurf.levels = self.subsurf_levels
        subsurf.render_levels = self.subsurf_levels
        cast.factor = 1

        bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="Subsurface")
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="Cast")

        return {'FINISHED'}


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator("mesh.add_block_sphere")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(BlockSphere)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_add.prepend(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(BlockSphere)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_add.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.mesh.add_block_sphere()
```

---

The console output is as follows.

```
Read prefs: C:\Users\trues\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.91\config\userpref.blend
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\python
Info: Deleted 1 object(s)

fake_module: addon missing 'bl_info' gives bad performance!: 'C:\\Users\\trues\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.91\\scripts\\addons\\block_sphere.py'
fake_module: addon missing 'bl_info' gives bad performance!: 'C:\\Users\\trues\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.91\\scripts\\addons\\block_sphere.py'
fake_module: addon missing 'bl_info' gives bad performance!: 'C:\\Users\\trues\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.91\\scripts\\addons\\block_sphere.py'
Modules Installed () from 'D:\\Files\\block_sphere.py' into 'C:\\Users\\trues\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.91\\scripts\\addons'
fake_module: addon missing 'bl_info' gives bad performance!: 'C:\\Users\\trues\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.91\\scripts\\addons\\block_sphere.py'
addon_utils.disable: block_sphere not disabled
Modules Installed (block_sphere) from 'D:\\Files\\block_sphere.py' into 'C:\\Users\\trues\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.91\\scripts\\addons'
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\ant_landscape\ant_functions.py", line 138, in poll
    return (ob.ant_landscape and not ob.ant_landscape.sphere_mesh)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ant_landscape'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\ant_landscape\ant_functions.py", line 187, in poll
    if ob.mode == 'EDIT':
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mode'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\ant_landscape\ant_functions.py", line 138, in poll
    return (ob.ant_landscape and not ob.ant_landscape.sphere_mesh)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ant_landscape'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\ant_landscape\ant_functions.py", line 187, in poll
    if ob.mode == 'EDIT':
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mode'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Comment: Don't know about ant,  but since 2.90, [you have to add it to a menu for operator search to find it](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.90/Python_API).

Comment: @scurest Ah, well I guess I needed to look at more recent tutorials for making add-ons, in that case. Would you recommend I look to any particular place to learn how to add the operator to a menu?

Comment: Just copy it from a default addon. [Here's](https://github.com/sobotka/blender-addons/blob/bcd08a9506d33bdd7358201031b04d041ef22d94/io_scene_obj/__init__.py#L477-L507) the OBJ addon for example.

Comment: @scurest So, I've tried adding code to add the script to a menu, but it's still not appearing in blender. I'm updating the question with the most recent version of the code, as I type this comment.

Comment: The code you've posted works for me. The option shows up in the Add menu and the operator search.

Comment: As a side note similar functionality is available via "Add Mesh Extra Objects"  from menu _Add > Mesh > Round Cube_ and select the "Quad Cube" preset.

Comment: @batFINGER That's actually good to know, because I have that add-on and wasn't aware of that functionality. Ultimately, though, this is meant as a learning process.

Also, I've gone ahead and made your recommended updates to the code.

This is what I get after starting up blender, deleting the cube, installing the add-on via preferences, and then trying to search for the functionality:
https://i.imgur.com/tOSqER5.png
https://i.imgur.com/0mZuqmb.png

Comment: Similarly to scurest have no issues either installing, it being in menu or in search in 2.91.  Also similarly given the error message in question is complaining about no `bl_info` dict, **but** your code has one, the issue is quite possibly the "trash" you have left behind in your addon folder.  Look for system console messages whinging about addons with same names etc, check the path on the addon info when enabling etc, etc.

Comment: btw the issues wtth ant landscape appear to be re its code for poll methods where `ob` is context object .. `return ob.foo == "bar"` failing if `ob is None` and should prob be edited to `return ob and ob.foo == "bar"` & have nothing to do with your addon, other than you have left blender in a state where `context.object is None`.  (like after a delete _"Info: Deleted 1 objects"_)

Comment: One more suggestion name it "BlockSphere" or something, other than "Cube".  IMO works well, hence upvoted. Someone else had a similar issue re addon not showing, where it worked for others, can't remember if it was resolved,  will post a link if I track it down.

Comment: Well, I've taken a look in my addon folder and the only thing there is the script I myself have made (Don't mind my endless sea of tabs) https://i.imgur.com/E3sk7ST.png

Comment: Are you using the Blender text editor to code or do you use an external IDE ?

Comment: @Gorgious I wrote the initial code in the blender text editor but then, after deciding to make it into a proper add-on, I copied the text over to another file which I've only edited with Notepad++.